# Oracle BI — How can I create custom graphs?

Tags: oracle-bi

Could you please help me to understand how can I create custom graphs (i.e. my own HTML+CSS) in Oracle BI?

I plan to design a dashboard and I need a very specific visualization (several interconnected circles segmented inside with fill % and color depending on different data sources) that is not available in stock graphs palette, and I can’t find any documentation on how to extend the palette.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what technology you're aiming to you. Here's an example from ages ago about using D3js and calendar charts:
https://dimensionality.ch/2012/08/14/d3js-calendar-configuration-in-obiee-11g/